# Spring-boot build configuration resets property files previously filled by maven install

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven, spring-boot projet with multiple profiles.

I clean install with maven for any profile. It creates the target folder and populates the properties files in the target folder with the values from the active profile.

When I run the spring build configuration it resets the properties to their template values.

But if I run maven clean install a second time the spring-boot build configuration doesn't reset the properties and works fine.

I'm using intellij.

---

A part of my application.properties:

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=@management.endpoint.metrics.enabled@ 
management.health.ldap.enabled=@management.health.ldap.enabled@ 
management.health.db.enabled=@management.health.db.enabled@ 
management.health.diskspace.enabled=@management.health.diskspace.enabled@ 
management.health.mail.enabled=@management.health.mail.enabled@ 
management.health.jms.enabled=@management.health.jms.enabled@
```

---

My profile properties file :

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=false   
management.health.ldap.enabled=false   
management.health.db.enabled=false
management.health.diskspace.enabled=false    
management.health.mail.enabled=false   
management.health.jms.enabled=false
```

---

My profile configuration:

```
<profile>
 <id>dev</id>
 <properties>
  <environment>dev</environment>
 </properties>
 <build>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/.jks</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <filters>
   <filter>
    ../src/filters/filter-${environment}.properties
   </filter>
  </filters>
 </build>
</profile>
```

---

My spring-boot class template

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateSitePublique")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateSitePublique() {
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplatePsn")
    public RestTemplate restTemplatePsn() {
    }


    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateProxyMetier")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateProxyMetier() {
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper myObjectMapper() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initSsl() {
    }

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
    }
}
```

---

My spring-boot build configuration
[image: spring-boot build configuration]

Comment: Is there a good reason why are you not using spring profiles ? like `application.properties` and `application-dev.properties` etc.?

Comment: @khmarbaise They don't serve the same purpose. Maven profiles are for build time solutions and spring for run time

Comment: Yes I know that ...and exactly that's the point and why are you mixing those different concepts? That does not make sense for a usual spring boot application...use the spring boot profiles...use the default spring profile (`application.properties`) which could be part of prod location in `src/main/resources` and other maybe only for testing purposes if really needed maybe

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a lot of things set up in my profiles and the development team doesn't manage all of the enviroments. We can't only use spring profiles. 
But are you saying the problem is spring-boot? Is spring-boot incompatible with maven profiles?

Comment: No I'm saying the same thing as yourself those concepts are two different things and shouldn't been mixed up...and it does not matter if the dev team doesn't manage them..this sounds like this should be moved to a infrastructure area or maybe something like spring cloud config (https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config)...because the configuration shouldn't be part of the distributed jar...should be given from outside...

Comment: @khmarbaise the configuration is not part of the distributed jar. That's only for the local environment.  
What is being mixed up?

Comment: the "spring-boot-parent-maven(resp. gradle)-resource-filtering"  works only on/after (maven) `process-resources` (or the gradle correspondent), when you run it "with something else", "something else" has to copy/replace...

Comment: If that's the case then is becomes more and more strange. Why do you use resource filtering (and a maven profile) for things which don't change simply put a file on the local directory and give it as start parameter... either in command line or in IDE as well... there is no need for profiles in such case at all...or use a separate configuration directory which can also being define on spring boot command line or using a default directory (`config` take a deep look into spring boot documentation).

Comment: It could be that when IDE uses it's own build, the resources are not filtered. Does using this action help: https://monosnap.com/file/AalIpQzSgnsDJptk14NiNHqpZB6NfD

Comment: Try set up Maven filtering to be executed after the IDE build: https://monosnap.com/file/5tcBXeQsZiNpGditp6GlEhXvJSxRjG Also try using different values for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Phase to be used for folders update**.